# How to pass login data between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I am  relatively new in this area and I'm working on simple windows form applicaton, so my idea is to make login form for user which is called from main form by clicking on Login button.

I want those login data stored in variables like "userpass" and "username" so I can add them in string for login and use them later for connecting on SQL server when I need to get some data from database.

---

### Login form code

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data 
    Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=baza;Persist 
    Security Info=True;User ID=" + boxUsername.Text.ToString().Trim() + 
    ";Password=" + boxPass.Text.ToString().Trim() );
    con.Open();

    if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)      
        {   Form1.username = boxUsername.Text.ToString();
            Form1.userpass = boxPass.Text.ToString();
             this.Hide();
        }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password."); }
```

---

### Main form code

```
    public static string username; 
    public static string userpass; 

    public string conn = "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial 
    Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True; Trusted_Connection=False; 
    User ID=" +username+ "; Password=" +userpass;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
    con.Open();
```

---

Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user ''.'
C# interactive says 
error CS0103: The name 'username' does not exist in the current context
error CS0103: The name 'userpass' does not exist in the current context

In login form it is working as it should, but when I call userpass and username variables in main form I can write them as text in messagebox and see values, but I can't use them in connection string for sql query. When I try to run sql query it shows System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do not initialize the connection string outside of a function. Something like this

```
public string conn;

public void GetInformationFromDatabase()
{
    conn = "Data Source=server.database.windows.net;Initial 
    Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True; Trusted_Connection=False; 
    User ID=" +username+ "; Password=" +userpass;
}
```